# How to write textviews vertically for Android Application development?

Tags: xml, string, textview, orientation, letter

I am stucked at a point on my application development. My intention is to display the textviews horizontally which will consist of some strings and I want to display them letter by letter from up to down. Let me give an example ;

```
T E X T V I E W
E D F O I Q L O
X I A Y E   E L
A N C O N   P F
S B T T A   H
  U O A     A
  R R       N
  G         T
```

As you see my strings are TEXAS , EDINBURG , etc.
I set these strings to textviews.
On the other hand , using textviews for such task may not be good and there may be some other alternatives for this, I am open to new ideas. Since i am not well experienced I could not figure out any other solutions.
I tried with vertical orientation but couldn't manage to display letter by letter.
Does anyone have an idea or experience about this concept ?
By the way I am using ECLIPSE- ADT.

Comment: You want to write  same test  in both  horizontally  and vertically ?

Comment: what do you mean by saying same test ? The default textviews work horizontally but I only need my strings to be displayed vertically as you see in the sample. 

EDFOIQLO , XIAYE EL , ANCON PF , .. these are irrelevant and meaningless things , they are all created by the words written vertically if you are asking those things